# How can I find the value of $XDG_CONFIG_HOME, $XDG_CONFIG_HOME, $XDG_STATE_HOME, etc in a Bash script?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, xdg, freedesktop, xdg-user-dirs

This seems like a simple question that every application developer would have, but I can't find the answer.

Per the latest [XDG Basedir Spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/basedir-spec/), there are many directories that should be defined in environment variables. As one example:

> There is a single base directory relative to which user-specific configuration files should be written. This directory is defined by the environment variable $XDG_CONFIG_HOME.

Let's say my Bash script saves a user config - and I want to follow the XDG spec - How do I find `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`? It makes sense that you would do something like

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Print out $XDG_CONFIG_HOME
echo Your XDG_CONFIG_HOME is: [$XDG_CONFIG_HOME]
```

But running this on a fresh Ubuntu and Fedora Silverblue install both give the output:

```
$ ./test.sh
Your XDG_CONFIG_HOME is: []
```

Which seems totally useless, since that would mean on fresh desktop installs of Ubuntu and Fedora Silverblue, my app would write config files into the running directory. Yet, I can see so many applications properly putting the data in `~/.config/`. Where are these apps finding the XDG environment variables, and how can I find them too?

Answer (score 2):

The spec [explains how to handle missing values](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html):

> If `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is either not set or empty, a default equal to `$HOME`/.local/share should be used.

and so on for all the XDG variables.

As a result of this, desktop environments often only set the values when their do *not* match the default. In your scripts, use expansions such as `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}` with the appropriate defaults for each variable.